# Изменение порядка появления элементов в Vertical Layout Group

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы каждый созданный  элемент в вертикальной лэйаут группе появлялся не в конце всех уже имеющихся элементов, а в начале и сдвигал все, созданные до этого, элементы вниз.

Ниже показан неправильный вариант. Надеюсь понятно что я имею ввиду.

[image: вот так не правильно]

Comment: попробуйте `transform.SetAsFirstSibling();` вызвать у элемента после того как прицепили его к лейаут группе

Comment: @trollingchar , Ваш комментарий едва ли не единственное верное решение. Оформите, пожалуйста, в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Горизонтальные и вертикальные лейаут группы, в отличие от **GridLayoutGroup**, не имеют такой настройки как **Start Corner** и **Start Axis**. Поэтому нам нужно сделать дочерний элемент самым первым, а для этого сначала прицепим элемент к лейаут группе, а потом выполним:

```
transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
```

где `transform` принадлежит тому элементу, который мы добавляем.